# WAMP Server installed on Windows Server 2008 R2 not accessible throughout LAN

Tags: apache, windows-server-2008-r2, wampserver

I've installed wampserver 2.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit and made necessary changes in apache `httpd.conf` as bellow :

```
<Directory "cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Also, inbound rule to allow 80 port is added in windows firewall. Still it is not visible to other on LAN. I'm not regular user of windows server so I googled for quick solution, please your suggestions to this problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not actually a change and only effects the cgi-bin directory and not the DocumentRoot folder.

Locate this section of your httpd.conf file

```
    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require local
```

Now lets assume your internal subnet ip address's are 192.168.1.*

You now have to add the instruction to tell Apache that it is allowed to accept connections from ip's in that range, like so

```
    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require local
    Require ip 192.168.1
```

Note the use of just 3 of the 4 quartiles of the ip address.

This will allow any ip address in the range 192.168.1.0 to 192.168.1.255 i.e. the whole subnet. *Change the subnet to match your actual ip address in use at your site.*

If you want you can be more specific like so if you actually need to be.

```
    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require local
    Require ip 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.11 192.168.1.12
```